# Rotating towards a target in top-down 2D game

Tags: unity, 2d, rotation, vector

I use the following code to rotate a transform towards another. And it's working fine. However, I want to lerp it over time period.

```
public void RotateToward(Transform target)
{ 
  Vector3 from = transform.up; 
  Vector3 to = target.position - transform.position;

  float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(from, to, transform.forward);
  transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, angle); 
}
```

An example would greatly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the speed with which your gameObject is allowed to rotate, then the Methods [`Vector3.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html) or [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) can help you. They can be used to turn an object towards the desired direction, but put a limit on how far the object is allowed to turn by specifying a `maxDegreeDelta` parameter.

```
Vector3 current = transform.forward;
Vector3 to = target.position - transform.position;
transform.forward = Vector3.RotateTowards(current, to, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime)
```

The variable `turnSpeed` should be a public inspector variable. The unit is degree per second.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for rotations you use slerp. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html

A basic rotation script is something along the lines:

```
    private float _timeRotation = 0f;
    private float _speed = 1f;
    private Transform _fromPos;
    private Transform _toPos;
    private bool _isRotating = false;
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (_isRotating)
            DoRotation();
    }

    public void Rotate(Transform from, Transform to)
    {
        _timeRotation = 0f;
        _isRotating = true;
        _fromPos = from;
        _toPos = to;
    }

    void DoRotation()
    {
        _timeRotation = _timeRotation + Time.deltaTime * _speed;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(_fromPos.rotation, _toPos.rotation, _timeRotation);
        if (_timeRotation >= 1f)
            _isRotating = false;
    }
```